# JSON string is weird

Tags: android, json, httpresponse

I send JSON at node : `response.json(object);`

and I get json at android :

```
 String json_string = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

And json_string from android :

```
"{\"query\":{\"count\":4,\"created\":\"2014-11-07T15:10:16Z\",\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"diagnostics\":{\"publiclyCallable\":\"true\", ~ }
```

It's different from what I generally got.

character `'"'` and `'\'`  is added to json string
So I'm troubling in getting the result from json string.

Is there something wrong?

Comment: That's because the `toString` method of json escapes characters. That's the expected behavior.

Comment: Really? Thank you for answering, Is there any way that you know to solve this?

Comment: There is nothing to solve because this is not a problem. You can however replace `\"` for `"` if it's that what you want.

Comment: I got a JSONException becase that string value can not convert to JSONObject ...

Comment: What are you trying to do? That JSON is correct. Why don't you just create an object from it? I don't understand..

Comment: Is my answer work for you then mark it right. Please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its okk, You are getting just  raw json. 
Do one thing  cast this string in StringBuilder and again StringBuilder to string. Its remove all "\ character. Try this its works for me

Comment: Yes, try this StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(string);

Answer (score 2):

Your string is just escaped, to keep special characters like double quotes. If there was no escaping, then your string would look just like that:

```
"{\"
```

So you need to indicate that some of double quotes shouldn't be treaded like end of the string.
Refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html